# List on Angular loosing values after calling a API service

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am working in an Angular app using version 7 and Web Api on .Net core. As of now, the communication between the two are OK. Well, almost :)

I am running into a particular scenario:

1. I'm using template driven form and two way binding to populate an object (it works fine)
2. That object is being passed as a parameter on an HTTP Post call that is made to the Web API to save the information.
3. The data is saved successfully on the DB and a response is send back to the Angular app
4. For some reason that I still don't understand, besides the object that was passed now is undefined, there are other variables that lost its values after that http call.

This is the code:

myComponent.ts

```
addStudent(form: NgForm): void {
    if (form.valid) {
      this.studentService.saveStudent(this.newStudent).subscribe(
        result => {
          console.log('success adding new student: ', result);
          this.newStudent.id = result.id;
        },
        error => console.log('error: ', error),
      );

      $('#modalStudent .close').click();
    }
}

ngOnInit() {
this.lookupService.getListOfSubjects('SubjectType').subscribe(
  data => (
    console.log('successfully loaded subject types'),
    this.subjectTypesList = data
  ),
  error => this.errorMessage = error as any,
);

if (this.errorMessage) { console.log(this.errorMessage); }
}
```

StudentModel.ts

```
export class Student {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    age: string;
    sex: string;
    subject: SubjectType;
}

export class SubjectType {
    id: number;
    description: string;
}
```

studentService.ts

```
saveStudent(studentToSave: Student): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = { headers };

    return this.http.post(this.myUrl + '/Students', studentToSave, options).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('Saved Student: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError),
    );
}
```

As you can see in the code, after calling the studentService.saveStudent() method:

1. The this.newStudent becomes undefined
2. The this.subjectTypesList object lost one its values and set it to null

subjectTypesList **Before** calling the service:

```
[0]: {
    $type: ""
    description: "Subject 1"
    id: 23
}
[1]: {
    $type: ""
    description: "Subject 2"
    id: 22
}
```

subjectTypesList **After** calling the service:

```
[0]: {
    $type: ""
    description: "Subject 1"
    id: null
}
[1]: {
    $type: ""
    description: "Subject 2"
    id: 22
}
```

I tried to google it to know why it is happening but no luck as of now.

Does any one knows why those variables are losing its data?

Regards!

Comment: What is calling addStudent and what is the saveStudent code

Comment: The addStudent is being called from the form tag in HTML: <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addStudent(form)">

Comment: saveStudent is the real service that calls the Web API. I have updated my post.

Comment: saveStudent is not returning data?

Comment: Yes, it's returning a JSON response. Basically, the same information that was passed on the variable this.newStudent plus the value of the id generated on back-end.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the this.newStudent.id = result.id

```
result => {
          console.log('success adding new student: ', result);
          **this.newStudent.id = result.id;**
        },
```

Inspect the HTTP response and verify that the result.id is not null. If it's null, you've found your issue.

Comment: Hi @thenolin, I already done that. the result object is having all the information as part of the http response that is send back. result.id is always different than null.

Comment: The problem is on the variable subjectTypesList, is setting to null the id associated with the one that was assigned to the this.newStudent object.

Comment: Whatever data you have coming back from your service call is either not coming back correctly or the model you have is mapped wrong. What does the http response look like?